# How to add a custom provider to Android Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am looking for a way to add my own app's images to the android gallery.

The app links to a server and will (on-demand) download images from the server.  It wouldn't be appropriate to simply download all images from the server because there may be too many much for the phone to hold.

It feels like this should be possible because of the existing ability to get images from apps like Facebook (See screenshot).

[image: Gallery screen shot showing "Content to Display"]

After Looking on google I tried creating a stub [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) that simply logs any requests, and found that the my provider is never touched when the user opens the Gallery app.

So either:

1. I missed a step
2. It's not possible to do what I want
3. It is possible, but I need to do something entirely different to make it happen

FYI my manifest contains:

```
    <provider
        android:authorities="couling.mycustomgallery"
        android:name=".CustomContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: There are ~2 billion Android devices. These are spread across thousands of device models from hundreds of manufacturers. There is no single "the android gallery". There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of gallery applications pre-installed on these devices, and many more available from the Play Store and elsewhere. None have to offer integration with Dropbox, Facebook, or Picasa. You happen to have a gallery that does offer such integration. Whether that integration is extensible to arbitrary apps is up to the gallery app developers. So, contact them and ask how to get your stuff in their app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Having never seen an android Phone / Tablet without a pre-installed one I was of the impression there may be a common interface which allows a gallery app to view all content (via `ContentProvider`?) in a similar way that contacts from different third-party apps are merged and displayed in a contact's app.  Are you saying that no such interface exists?

Comment: I am saying that gallery apps do not have to use such an interface, if one exists. A `ContentProvider` alone would be insufficient, just as having a Web site that nothing links to will not cause that site to get indexed by a search engine. Something has to tell the search engine that the site exists; similarly, something would have to tell the gallery that your provider exists. I am not aware of any standard mechanism for this, though I haven't gone looking for one.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I assume it is not possible.

Long answer:

Android Photo Gallery apps i have seen so far use `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI="content://media/external/images/media"` 
as content-uri-api to query against.

May be Dropbox, Facebook, or Picasa have found a way to include their external images as entries there (and in `content://media/external/images/thumbnails`) , too.
But i assume they have their own content-uri-api for this.

You can use https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.k3b.android.contentproviderhelper to analyse the different contentproviders and find out if you see Dropbox, Facebook, or Picasa data under `content://media/external/images/media` or under some other uri.

Since android-4.4 there is a standard for picking a document (i.e. of mimetype "image/*") via [android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) which you can implemt.